# Retrieve entered text from alert box.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

OK I am trying to retrieve a variable from this text field from this example http://junecloud.com/journal/code/displaying-a-password-or-text-entry-prompt-on-the-iphone.html.  He says to do this :
"To get the text entered you just need to set a delegate for the text field and the alert, as shown in the example code above. Then you can use textFieldDidEndEditing: to get the value and store it somewhere temporary. When alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: is called, you can look up the saved value, and either use it or discard it depending on what button was pressed."
 Thing is I'm so new to iOS and objective c that this means nothing to me. To me the text field delegate is set to self-- passwordField.delegate = self;  Does anyone have an example to show? So I can see how to retrieve the entered text.

```
UIAlertView *passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Phone Number" message:@"\n\n\n"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil), nil];

UILabel *passwordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,40,260,25)];
passwordLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
passwordLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
passwordLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
passwordLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);
passwordLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
passwordLabel.text =@"Cell Phone Number xxx-xxx-xxxx";
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordLabel];

UIImageView *passwordImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"passwordfield" ofType:@"png"]]];
passwordImage.frame = CGRectMake(11,79,262,31);
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordImage];

UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,83,252,25)];
passwordField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
passwordField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
passwordField.delegate = self;
[passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
[passwordAlert addSubview:passwordField];

[passwordAlert setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,9)];
[passwordAlert show];
[passwordAlert release];
[passwordField release];
[passwordImage release];
[passwordLabel release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method in the same class:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *textValue = textField.text;
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", textValue);
}
```

Comment: NSString *textValue = textField.text;   take out the "[" before textField